# Pymongo sort in embedded array

Tags: python, сортировка, pymongo

Имеется база данных MongoDB такого типа:

```
{
 'Date': '2017-12-15',
 'Values': [{'Temp': 42},
            {'Temp': 36},
            {'Temp': 38},
            {'Temp': 40}]
}
{
 'Date': '2017-12-16',
 'Values': [{'Temp': 45},
            {'Temp': 38},
            {'Temp': 49},
            {'Temp': 52}]
 }
```

Необходимо используя pymongo найти 5 наибольших значений Temp независимо от даты.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно попробовать использовать `distinct` и запросить объединенный список температур, а потом просто взять от него 5 значений.

```
collection.distinct("Values.Temp")[-5:]
```

Если значений очень много, то такой вариант не подойдет.

Comment: А значения вернутся отсортированными?

Comment: Да, в возврастающем порядке.